# Is there any accurate way of calculating size of UILabel without using sizeToFit?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, sizetofit

I know this question is a long shot, but I am just wondering if someone found a better solution. Using boundingRect is not accurate as it does not work with word wrapping. The reason I do not wish to use sizeToFit is that it incurs quite a hefty performance penalty when there are a lot of labels to calculate, thus causing jerkiness during scrolling (I am using UICollectionView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the internal method that makes `sizeToFit` possible - `sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize`. You can use it to compute the size without actually relayouting the view.

Except that there's nothing more. There's a lot of methods, as you mentioned that compute bounding boxes of strings with different fonts/attributes/whatever, but they are always a little off, as the UI controls have inner layout or margins that are not publicly accessible. Even if you get it to work now it changes heavily from iOS to iOS.

As a solution I propose caching the sizes. Invalidate on model changes, rotations or collection view width changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will test out the performance and update with the results soon.

Comment: sizeThatFits does return the right results, but overall I still cannot solve the jerkiness issue, which I believe the AsyncDisplayKit is made for.

Comment: just run instruments time profiler and reproduce the jankiness

Comment: Yes, I am using the instruments profiler, but I do not think its an issue that can be fixed easily. In my case I am using the UICollectionView, and the cellforrowatindexpath method has to be super optimal before it starts dropping frames. My cell has a lot of components which has dynamic height, and it makes it so much more complex. AsyncDisplayKit (now called Texture) is what I am using now, and so far it works great, I highly recommend it.

Comment: I recommend also trying just layoutSubviews or just computing height manually (based on the layout) without using `sizeThatFits`

Comment: Thats the problem that I was struggling with. If say, I am using a UILabel with NSLineBreakbyWordWrap, the calculations are always slightly off, but the minor difference can trigger an extra line, and it will throw off the whole calculations of the height.

Comment: You should paste your code doing this as the question actually and get an answer where is your mistake, as you can do this perfectly

Comment: The code is quite complicated so its difficult to post. I was using this library (https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView), and when you create a lot of tags in each UICollectionViewCell, you will notice the lag, coz all calculations are done on the UI thread.